# Wordpress - Media Image Slug/Permalink - Change Renaming Upload Logic

Tags: wordpress, media, permalinks

When I upload an image to Wordpress with the name:

- Image20_O9KA M 21.jpg
  Wordpress will change the permalink to:
- Image20_09KA-M-21.jpg

I would need the format:

- Image_09KA_M_21.jpg

How can I get that format automatically when uploading new images?

Comment: SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist, and what specific problem you need help with. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can try below filter.

```
function prefix_file_rename_on_upload( $filename ) {
    return str_replace('Image20', 'Image', $filename)
}
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'prefix_file_rename_on_upload', 10 );
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Same method as [@Akhtarujjaman Shuvo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6286562/akhtarujjaman-shuvo) but replacing the `$filename` whitespaces and hyphens with underscores before returning through the `sanitize_file_name` filter...

```php
function sanitize_file_name_with_underscores($filename) {
    return str_replace([' ','-'], ['_','_'], $filename)
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'sanitize_file_name_with_underscores', 10 );
```

In theory (not tested)...

- Uploaded filename: `Image20_O9KA M 21.jpg`
- Filename result: `Image20_O9KA_M_21.jpg`